# Can Kafka Streams consume message in a format and produce another format such as AVRO message

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am using kafka streams to consume JSON string from one topic, process and generate response to be stored in another topic. However the message that needs to be produced to the response topic needs to be in avro format.

I have tried using key as string serde and value as **SpecificAvroSerde**

Following is my Code to create Topology:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<Object, Object> consumerStream =builder.stream(kafkaConfiguration.getConsumerTopic());
consumerStream = consumerStream.map(getKeyValueMapper(keyValueMapperClassName));
consumerStream.to(kafkaConfiguration.getProducerTopic());
```

Following is my config

```
    if (schemaRegistry != null && schemaRegistry.length > 0) {
        streamsConfig.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, String.join(",", schemaRegistry));          
    }
    streamsConfig.put(this.keySerializerKeyName, StringSerde.class);
    streamsConfig.put(this.valueSerialzerKeyName, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
    streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
    streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, batchSize);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, FailOnInvalidTimestamp.class);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, processingGuarantee);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, Integer.parseInt(commitIntervalMs));
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, numberOfThreads);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, replicationFactor);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, DeserializationExceptionHandler.class);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, ProductionExceptionHandler.class);
    streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION,StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);
    streamsConfig.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, compressionMode);
    streamsConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
```

I am seeing the following error when I try with the example:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

Comment: As Nishu pointed out, you need to set the correct Serdes on the source and sink to make it work. As an alternative to Kafka Streams, you could also try out KSQL (that uses Kafka Stream as it's runtime) and let's you convert data between JSON/Avro very easily: https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/changing-data-serialization-format-json-avro

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax This is interesting too. Will try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the Key Value Serdes. You should use the correct serdes while consuming the stream and same for while publishing the stream.

In case if your input is JSON and you want to publish as Avro, you can do it as following:

```
Properties streamsConfig= new Properties();
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<Object, Object> consumerStream =builder.stream(kafkaConfiguration.getConsumerTopic(),Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

// Replace AvroObjectClass with your avro object type
KStream<String,AvroObjectClass> consumerAvroStream = consumerStream.map(getKeyValueMapper(keyValueMapperClassName));
consumerAvroStream.to(kafkaConfiguration.getProducerTopic());
```

Comment: Yup. Could not update earlier. Resolved it using same thing. Following is what my code looks like now 
`consumerStream.to(kafkaConfiguration.getProducerTopic(), Produced.with(lKeySerde, lValueSerde));'

Thanks a ton @NishuTayal  your help.

Comment: Great! feel free to accept the answer, if it helped you. :)